# automake: substitute bin_PROGRAMS in DATA bash file

Tags: bash, autotools, automake

Is there any way to use the list of programs to build from a Makefile.am and put it in a bash script (autotools substitution, variables, ...)?

Something like below :

**Example**

*Makefile.am*

```
bin_PROGRAMS = prog1 prog2 prog3
[...]
```

*script.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
EXEC=@bin_PROGRAMS@ # something like this
```

The goal is to give this script the list of programs being built

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because substitution happens at configure time, while the Makefile stuff happens at make time.

However, you can ensure that both lists are defined at configure time:

**configure.ac**

```
AC_SUBST([PROGRAMS], [prog1 prog2 prog3])
```

**Makefile.am**

```
bin_PROGRAMS = @PROGRAMS@
```

**script.sh**

```
EXEC=@PROGRAMS@
```